# Correct way to end an observable stream in error

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have several methods which return IObservable. In all cases I set up a query which will cause the returned observable to complete. Generally I've been using the TakeUntil extension method. The observable type I'm using in the TakeUntil contains a flag that tells me if there has been a problem. How could I use this to cause my returned observable to end in error? I would love a TakeUntil overload that allowed the observable to end in error.

Currently I have hacked the method to return a subject which has subscribed to the query observable and also subscribed to other observable that I use in TakeUntil to either call OnCompleted or OnError. I realise this a bad plan but what should I be doing? Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike `TakeUntil`, you have to decide from one of three cases, corresponding to `OnNext`, `OnError` and `OnCompleteted`. And there's already a built-in type which captures it in `Notification<T>`.

All we need to do is transform concrete notifications into implicit ones - with the `Dematerialize` operator.

Here's an example stream which throws if the value 10 occurs in the stream, but completes it if any value is >= 9.

```
        var errorAt10 =
            values.Select(value =>
            {
                if (value == 10)
                    return Notification.CreateOnError<long>(new Exception());

                if (value >= 9)
                    return Notification.CreateOnCompleted<long>();

                return Notification.CreateOnNext(value);
            })
            .Dematerialize();
```

We could simplify this if we wanted to:

```
    public static IObservable<T> NotifyAs<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Func<T, NotificationKind> choice, Exception exception = default)
    {
        return source.Select(value =>
        {
            switch (choice(value))
            {
                case NotificationKind.OnError:
                    return Notification.CreateOnError<T>(exception ?? new Exception());
                case NotificationKind.OnCompleted:
                    return Notification.CreateOnCompleted<T>();
                default:
                    return Notification.CreateOnNext(value);
            }

        })
        .Dematerialize();
    }
```

Now you can rewrite the former example as:

```
        var errorAt10 =
            values.NotifyAs(value =>
                value == 10 ? NotificationKind.OnError :
                value >= 9 ? NotificationKind.OnCompleted :
                NotificationKind.OnNext
            );
```

Comment: Thanks Asti! Im not by my pc at the moment but i will have a play with this when I am.

Comment: Np. I hope this solved your problem of looking at flags in your values to decide to throw an exception or not.

Comment: Still havent got to my PC but have read around the types you are using and can now understand the code you wrote. Im pretty sure this is exactly what I need. Thanks for taking the time to answer. I'm a little surprised that there isn't a more standard way of doing this. It seems like a common use case or do people not use rx in this way?

Comment: Choose what's more semantically correct for you. Throwing errors are generally among the less used parts of Rx. And most people write new operators using `Create`, so it's handled there, and there are other ways, like using `SelectMany(Return|Throw)` to get what you want.

Comment: You're welcome. It's folks like you who make me feel good about answering questions. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to do anything. What you're asking for is already built-in.

If you start with this code:

```
var source = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
var ender = new Subject<Unit>();
var query = source.TakeUntil(ender);
query.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Then you only need to call `ender.OnError(new Exception("My exception"));` for the `source` observable to end in error with the exception `new Exception("My exception")`.

Comment: Thanks Enigmatively. My problem is that the ender observable i'm using in TakeUntil never throws an error.    It's just pushing several status flags. I need to look at the status flags to decide when to say there is a problem. I guess i could use the Do extension method to actually raise an exception?

Comment: @user5903849 - You can user the `Observable.Throw` method to throw an exception. It's just a matter of creating the right `SelectMany` on the `ender` observable so that it throws the exception that you want with a combination of `Observable.Throw` and `Observable.Return`.